# Что обозначают эти слова

Tags: значение-слов, значение

Ильины три поездочки:

> ...Вынимал да пускал Илья
> В дуб **кряковистый** разрывчатую>

А.П Чехов "Мальчики"

> Когда стало бизонов бежит через **пампасы**,то дрожит земля,а в это время мустанги,испугавшись,брыкаются и ржут>

Что такое "кряковистый" и "пампасы",развёрнутые ответы.

Заранее благодарствую

Comment: Кряж - | твердая, отдельная часть чего-либо, составляющая по себе целое. Кряж дерева, бревно, брус, колода, толстое голомя, отрубок, чурбан... Даль. Кряжистый - толстый, крепкий, подобный кряжу. Даль. 1. Невысокая горная цепь; холмистое плоскогорье. Горный кряж. Донецкий кряж.
2. Толстый короткий обрубок бревна из близкой к корню части дерева (обл., спец.). Ушаков.

Comment: Кряковистый тоже что кряжистый, но какое-то диалектное.

Comment: Пампасы географический термин, от pampa, исп. - название безлесных  равнин в Южной Америке.